# Quando o usuário clicar na imagem, abrir em tamanho maior

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<li class="editable" name="Galeria">
  <a href="./imagens/galeria.jpg" rel="">
    <img class="mudar" src="./imagens/galeria.jpg" title="" alt="" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Por exemplo, eu gostaria que quando o usuário clicasse no `<a>` de alguma forma abrisse uma janela (colorbox, lightbox?) com a imagem em tamanho real. Nunca fiz isso na mão, por isso estou perguntando.

Comment: Você precisa de uma galeria com zoom ou quer aprender a fazer uma?

Comment: Preciso de algo como colorbox. Pode ser algum plugin pronto. Tudo que fiz em colorbox com em WordPress. Nunca tive que instalar um na mão.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo-lhe o plugin responsivo [blueimp Gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/), você pode baixá-lo e dentro do zip haverá alguns exemplos, é bem simples, você linka o css e js (jquery é necessário), depois tem um script básico para carregar o plugin na página e depois é só usar a estrutura html que o site te da das imagens... Tem uma sessão de documentação do plugin... Qualquer dúvida, posta aqui...

---

Alterei para jquery em um projeto meu, acredito que possa lhe ajudar... Substituindo o id link por uma classe link na estrutura html...

```
$(function(){
            $('.link').each(function(){
                $(this).click(function(event){
                    event = event || window.event;
                    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
                        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
                        options = {index: link, event: event},
                        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
                    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
                });          
            });
        });
```

Comment: Show de bola cara, só tem um problema, nessa galeria eu estruturei em `ul` e `li` por causa de outro plugin que estou usando, e já uso um **id** na `ul`, existe algum **getElementById** equivalente para classes?